# Facebook Inbound replies through Nexmo API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, vonage

Am working on a facebook chat bot using Nexmos facebook message API with PHP. I succeeded in sending a message in sandbox to facebook. However, get a reply when through the inbound webhook call back is a hard nut now.

NEXMO documentation is not that well detailed to help me get done with the TASK.
Any Help on how i can the reply message when a user on facebook replies to the page's chat?

```
function inbound() {
        $this->load_model("Api_model")->save_inbound_prod_message($_POST);
    }
```

In that above code, i expected to have some data sent to me through $_POST however, the variable is empty.

THank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not mastered the art of PHP wit JSON data.
So this was solved by these simple lines of code

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
        //error_log($input);
        $input = json_decode($input);
        $psid = $input->from->id;
```

as you can see in the question, i expected the reply to be in $_POST variable which wasn't the case.